# "AMOUNT1" is not valid in the context where it is used

Tags: sql, db2

I'm executing the the following query in DB2:

```
select  
  SUM (orders.totalproduct
      +orders.TOTALTAX
      +orders.totalshipping
      -orders.totaladjustment) as amount1 
from 
  orders  
where 
  amount1>10000
```

The query is not executed, I get this exception instead:

> "AMOUNT1" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=3.64.96 SQL Code: -206, SQL State: 42703

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please, format your code properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create and use amount1 in same time in DB2.

Try this:

```
 select * from (
 select SUM (orders.totalproduct+orders.TOTALTAX+orders.totalshipping- orders.totaladjustment) as amount1 from orders 
 ) tmp where amount1>10000
```

or this:

```
select SUM (orders.totalproduct+orders.TOTALTAX+orders.totalshipping-  orders.totaladjustment) as amount1 from orders 
having  SUM (orders.totalproduct+orders.TOTALTAX+orders.totalshipping-orders.totaladjustment)>10000
```

Answer (score 0):

This topic was since answered, and my first example is a duplicate [but formatted differently]; there may be something of value/add in what I offer.

The name assigned to an expression on the SELECT column-list is not available for reference **within the scope** of every other clause of the same SELECT query; e.g. the name assigned there, is available for reference in an ORDER BY clause, but can not be reference in either a WHERE clause or HAVING clause -- thus, explains the error seen.

To avoid repeating the expression in the HAVING clause [noting: the aggregate is not allowed in a WHERE clause unless rewritten as a scalar subselect], **consider** assigning a name to the result of the expression within a *derived table expression*; that enables scoping of the name into the query of that derived table. By eliminating reference to a ***duplicate* expression**, that also prevents having to maintain the two copies identically, if any revisions need to be made to the query.

The table identifier and use of qualified column name shown here, are both optional, but included to be clear about whence the referenced name comes; examples show two ways to code a derived table for referencing the named expression.

```
select S.AMOUNT1
from table /* Nested Table Expression (NTE) */
  ( select 
      SUM ( orders.totalproduct
          + orders.TOTALTAX
          + orders.totalshipping
          - orders.totaladjustment
          ) as amount1 
    from orders
  ) as S
where S.amount1>10000

with /* Common Table Expression (CTE) */
  aggSum ( AMOUNT1 ) as
    ( select 
         SUM ( orders.totalproduct
             + orders.TOTALTAX
             + orders.totalshipping
             - orders.totaladjustment
             ) as amount1 /* named here; or, as shown, named above */
      from orders
    )
select C.AMOUNT1
from aggSum as C /* from the above (CTE) */
where C.amount1>10000
```

Although there is the following option as well [one that I doubt I would ever code, because], I find this much more difficult to read than having just made duplicate references to the expression in the HAVING clause [i.e. as shown in the second example in the accepted answer]. This query encapsulates the same aggregate query in a subquery as that is then referenced as a *scalar subselect* on the WHERE clause:

```
  select 
    SUM ( orders.totalproduct
        + orders.TOTALTAX
        + orders.totalshipping
        - orders.totaladjustment
        ) as amount1 
  from orders
  where ( select 
            SUM ( orders.totalproduct
                + orders.TOTALTAX
                + orders.totalshipping
                - orders.totaladjustment
                )
          from orders
        ) > 10000
```

Answer (score 0):

in db2, you can't use an alias you've created for your columns in the same sub query for the where/having.

Even in MySQL/BigQuery, I think you can only reference any aliases in the group by/order by/having statements, not the where.

Use a sub query and filter there, or copy the code for the column (WITHOUT the alias) and paste it in the where. But would recommend the sub query option.