# How to combine the results of different queries into one?

Tags: db2

I have the results of a sentiment analysis in one column. I'd like to show what each number represents and the count, like this:

```
 Neg | Neutral | Pos 
---------+-----+-----
  30 |   55    | 100
```

I've tried many different approaches I've found on the internet, to no avail. It seems the db2 syntax changes frequently, and all the documentation I've found does not work on my current bluemix account.

The closest I can get is with UNION:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) as NEGATIVE      FROM C7  WHERE SENTIMENT = 1
union
SELECT  COUNT(*) as NEUTRAL       FROM C7  WHERE SENTIMENT = 2
union
SELECT  COUNT(*) as Pos           FROM C7  WHERE SENTIMENT = 3
```

However, this gives me:

```
NEGATIVE
--------
   30
   55
  100
```

How can I combine the results of each query side-by-side?

---

I tried the answers from the post Pivoting in DB2, but I got errors:

```
SELECT 
  C7.SENTIMENT,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN C7.SENTIMENT = 1 THEN Value END) AS NEGATIVE,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN C7.SENTIMENT = 2 THEN Value END) AS NEUTRAL,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN C7.SENTIMENT = 3 THEN Value END) AS POSITIVE,
FROM C7
GROUP BY C7.SENTIMENT
```

> SQL0206N: SQL0206N "VALUE" is not valid in the context where it is used. SQLSTATE=42703

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  C7.SENTIMENT,
    (SELECT value  FROM C7  WHERE C7.SENTIMENT = 1) AS VERY_NEGATIVE,
    (SELECT value  FROM C7  WHERE C7.SENTIMENT = 2) AS NEGATIVE,
    (SELECT value  FROM C7  WHERE C7.SENTIMENT = 3) AS NEUTRAL
FROM C7
```

> SQL0206N: SQL0206N "VALUE" is not valid in the context where it is used. SQLSTATE=42703

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pivoting in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529107/pivoting-in-db2)

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Nope, tried all of those answers, non worked, will update my post with why it's not that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It likely thinks `VALUE` is being used as a keyword here (since it's a reserved word, although it can be used as a column name in at least some contexts).  But unless whatever you're trying to refer to can be null, you don't care what it holds, so you can substitute a constant value (`1` is a favorite).  (From my experience column-not-found yields a different exception, so not likely to stem from that)

Comment: Given [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39805576/amount1-is-not-valid-in-the-context-where-it-is-used), it's actually more likely that you were defining a new local column name (`<blah> as value`) that you were trying to use, which you didn't include in your statement.  If you switch to the source column, or just a constant value instead, do the existing answers work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so after reworking a few answers, I finally got what I was looking for:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  (SELECT COUNT(SENTIMENT) FROM C7 WHERE C7.SENTIMENT = 1) AS NEGATIVE,
  (SELECT COUNT(SENTIMENT) FROM C7 WHERE C7.SENTIMENT = 2) AS NEUTRAL,
  (SELECT COUNT(SENTIMENT) FROM C7 WHERE C7.SENTIMENT = 3) AS POSITIVE
FROM C7
```

This seems like something I hovered around for a long time, but couldn't find because some posts answer the question with bizarre table names, and values.

So basically, to get queries next to each other, you have to use multiple `SELECT`s.

Also, notice I used `DISTINCT` because otherwise it would have given a copy of the same data for every row in my database.

Comment: .... `DISTINCT` is unnecessary, since if you're going this route you should be doing something different, either putting all three of those into a `VALUES` statement, or using the dummy table (`sysibm.sysdummy1`) to give yourself the single row.  If you're lucky the system is able to look at that query and optimize out the `DISTINCT`, otherwise you're just penalizing yourself.