# SQL. Problem with header. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.26.14

Tags: sql, db2

I just started learning SQL. I got data with which I wanted to experiment but immediately got stuck. I use IBM Db2 on cloud to run queries where I uploaded a CSV file.

When I run the following query it works just fine:

```sql
select * from TableName
```

However, when I change it to the following query:

```sql
select Column1 from TableName
```

I get this error:

```
Column1 is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=4.26.14
```

I get similar errors with all other columns.

I'm guessing there is something wrong with the headers. I tried to upload the table without the headers, however, similar errors also occur with automatically generated column names.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: may be this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39805576/amount1-is-not-valid-in-the-context-where-it-is-used

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try like the below

```
  select Column1 from (select * from TableName)tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

In DB2 change all fields names to `UPPER` into `DB`.