# Problematic Case Statement in Db2

Tags: sql, db2, case

I have the following prompt regarding the sample database Db2 comes with.

> List the full names (first, middle, last) and education level (column
> labelled EDUCATION)  of all employees. The education level should be
> printed as 'GRADUATE' if 18 or greater;  'COLLEGE' if 16 or greater;
> and 'HIGH SCHOOL’ if less than 16. The column headings  should be
> FIRST, M, LAST, EDUCATION.

Here is my work:

```
SELECT firstnme AS first, midinit AS m, lastname AS last, 
  CASE 
    WHEN edlevel >= 18 THEN "GRADUATE" 
    WHEN edlevel < 16 THEN "HIGH SCHOOL" 
    ELSE "COLLEGE"
  END AS education 
FROM employee;
```

Here is the error message:

```
SQL0206N  "GRADUATE" is not valid in the context where it is used.  
SQLSTATE=42703
```

It works if I assign dummy integer values instead of "GRADUATE", "HIGH SCHOOL", and "COLLEGE", so it sounds like there is just some some very string-specific issue. Also, edlevel is originally a smallint. So, is my problem really the same one as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39805576/amount1-is-not-valid-in-the-context-where-it-is-used)?

Comment: In SQL " is used to quote identifiera that may otherwise violate naming conventions. String delimiter in SQL is ' as in 'Graduate'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using double quotes instead of single quote for string value. You could try this

```
SELECT firstnme AS first, midinit AS m, lastname AS last, 
  CASE 
    WHEN edlevel >= 18 THEN 'GRADUATE' 
    WHEN edlevel < 16 THEN 'HIGH SCHOOL' 
    ELSE 'COLLEGE'
  END AS education 
FROM employee;
```